# Cmake links multiple versions of boost/Cmake separate compilation of source files

Tags: c++, boost, cuda, cmake

I'm trying to build my project on a cluster, so I don't have any influence on the environment (ie no sudo). On my local machine I can get it to work.

Here the problem:
My project contains cuda files as well as c++ code. The latter one requires a library that needs gcc/g++ >6 (maybe >5 would work as well, afaik std=c++14). The cuda code on the other hand, as of cuda 7.5 needs gcc < 5.

I've already got this issue done by using the g++ 6.2.0 as standard compiler and pass the other gcc with -ccbin /path/to/gcc-4.x.

So my code compiles fine, but the problem is that it also uses the boost library, which needs to be a newer version on the cluster to work with the gcc 6.2.0 than the one I locally use. This is also not the problem itself, as linking the correct one does work, **BUT** when doing so, the nvcc still links an older version of boost (that is compatible with the gcc-4.x) and thus resulting in having multiple boost library version linked. This leads to segmentation faults during run time, whenever a function of the old boost library is used.

So a solution I was thinking about would be first compiling the c++ files and then only the cuda files, kinda like a simple makefile target would do:

```
foo: foo-class.o
  nvcc foo-class.o foo.cu -o foo
```

I'm currently unsure if this would solve the problem and if this is possible to do with cmake, but if that is not the case, is there a possibility to take care of the double linkage?

Minimal cmake file example of how mine currently looks:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(foo)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
set(LINKER_FLAGS "-lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lSDL2 -lSDL2main -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem")
set(ADDITIONAL_FLAGS "-g -Wno-error=switch")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 ${LINKER_FLAGS} ${ADDITIONAL_FLAGS}")

set(SOURCE_FILES
    runtime/main.cpp
    foo.cpp)

set(CUDA_FILES cuda/food.cu)

set(CUDA_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS "-ccbin /usr/bin/gcc --Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets")
set(CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR "/afs/crc.nd.edu/x86_64_linux/c/cuda/8.0/")
find_package(CUDA QUIET REQUIRED)
set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS OFF)
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS -g ${CUDA_ADDITIONAL_FLAGS})

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS program_options filesystem system regex REQUIRED)

cuda_add_executable(isosurfaces ${SOURCE_FILES} ${CUDA_FILES})


include_directories(~/lib/include)
include_directories(${BOOST_ROOT}/incldue)

target_link_libraries(foo ~/lib/lib/libThorSerialize17.so)
```

Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something completely obvious here, but why are you trying to link any host code with nvcc for anyway?

Comment: Is there a way to build one executable with cmake, that allows one part compiled with nvcc and one part with gcc/g++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve the CMake file I would suggest to use the variables provided by the Boost find script instead of manual setting (that will however most likely not help with the issue itself, but good in general):

```
find_package(Threads)
# set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON) # uncomment to try with static libs
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options filesystem system regex)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(isosurfaces
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
)

# remove -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
# from LINKER_FLAGS as provided better by ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
```

---

Regarding the issue itself with the different versions of Boost (if you really need to use Boost in the Cuda code for some reason), I'm afraid that will be quite difficult to get working in scope of a single executable. What you can do however, is to separate one of the modules (either the Cuda or the application code) to a **separate shared library**. That way it could work relatively straightforward, as the shared library can use a different Boost version than the rest of the application (you can experiment with using either static or shared Boost libraries, i.e. `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS` switched ON/OFF).

For example to create a shared library from the Cuda code you could do:

```
cuda_add_library(isosurfaces_cuda ${CUDA_FILES} SHARED)
add_executable(isosurfaces ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(isosurfaces
    isosurfaces_cuda
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
)
```

Then it could probably work, provided that you do not use Boost in the interface between the Cuda code and the remaining C++ code.

It can also help to use the visibility attribute and hide all symbols by default, so that the Boost library symbols will not be exported from the Cuda shared library (or the other way around, if the library is created from the remaining C++ code). For that the "`-fvisibility=hidden`" compiler flag and "`-Wl,--exclude-libs=ALL -Wl,--discard-all`" linker flags can be used.

Comment: I'm trying to build the project this way, and it seem like this should be the way to go. My only problem with this is that cuda_add_library uses the same compilation flags as the add_exectuable call, which is odd for me.

Comment: Hum, I actually didn't use Cuda with CMake yet, but I would suppose by default it uses the same flags, with perhaps some additional ones for the Cuda specifics. You can somewhat alter the Cuda library compile flags by using `set_target_properties(isosurfaces_cuda COMPILE_FLAGS "additional flags")`, but that will only add extra flags I think. So if you want different flags for Cuda and App, you could use `set_target_properties` also for the app and set the default CXX flags to only some basic set shared by both.

Comment: Thank you, your post was what finally helped me.
I separated the cuda part into a library, and then played around with where in the CMakeLists.txt I set the flags and I removed some flags.. eventually I got it to work. I don't exactly know how/why, but it works.